# Infix to postfix assignment

Tags: java, eclipse, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I've been stuck on this program for about a week and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I can't get the operands and operators to print in the proper spot and the '(' ')' won't delete. Here's what I have so far. HELP!!!

```
public static int precedence(char token) {
            if (token == '^') {
                return 1; // Lowest precedence
                } else if (token == '+' || token == '-') {
                    return 2;
                    } else if (token == '*' || token == '/') {
                        return 3;
                        } else
                            return -1;
            }
        
        // method to convert infox => postfix
        public  static String infixToPostfix(String infix){
            MyStackTiara<Character> operator = new MyStackTiara<>(); // 1. Create an empty stack
            String postfix = ""; // Create an empty string stack
            MyStackTiara<Character> noNeed = new MyStackTiara<>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++) {// Scan input from left to right
                char token = infix.charAt(i); // Current character
                
                if (token == '(') {
                    operator.push(token);
                } else if (token >= '0' || token <= '9') {
                    // Check for operand and append to string
                    postfix += token;
                }  else if (token == ')') {
                    while (!operator.isEmpty()) {
                        if (operator.peek() == '(') {
                            noNeed.push(operator.pop());
                            break;
                        } else
                            operator.pop();
                    }
                
                    //operator.pop();
                } else if (token == '*' || token == '/' || token == '+' || token == '-' || token == '^') {
                    if (token == '^') {
                        char op3 = operator.pop();
                        char operand1 = operator.pop();
                        char operand2 = operator.pop();
                        
                        String newPostfix = postfix + operand2 + operand1 + op3;
                        
                        postfix += newPostfix;
                        } else if (token == '+' || token == '-') {
                            char op2 = operator.pop();
                            char operand1 = operator.pop();
                            char operand2 = operator.pop();
                            
                            String newPostfix = postfix + operand2 + operand1 + op2;
                            
                            postfix += newPostfix;
                            } else if (token == '*' || token == '/') {
                                char op1 = operator.pop();
                                char operand1 = operator.pop();
                                char operand2 = operator.pop();
                                
                                String newPostfix = postfix + operand2 + operand1 + op1;
                                
                                postfix += newPostfix;
                                }
                        }
                }
            return postfix;
        }
```

When the infix is: (4-2)*(2+3)

I want it to print: 42-23+

But it's printing: 4-2)*2+3)

Comment: There are much simpler expressions which your code doesn't handle correctly -- e.g. "4-2" prints "4-2" instead of "42-". I suggest that you step through your code with the debugger while it processes a simple expression.

Comment: In particular, think about `token >= '0' || token <= '9'` -- what *exactly* does that do?

Comment: My goal was to check if the token was a digit, but now that you ask, it may make more sense to check if the token isn't an operator or parentheses.

Comment: Does `token >= '0' || token <= '9'` check whether the token is a digit? Is it true or false when `token` is `'('`? What does the `||` operator do?

Comment: And have you stepped through your code with the debugger? That is the first thing you should do.